# Implementing jQuery AJAX from within Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I used a [tutorial from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-1-constraint-validation-html/) to help me with HTML5 Constraint Validation for my application's client-side validation. I would like to introduce an AJAX script that submits the form to prevent reloading the page (as the form is displayed in a modal pop-up that I don't want closing on submit.)

From what I have gathered online, it seems the best way to do this is to use jQuery. However, the validation script is written in regular ol' Javascript.

I'm kind of confused as to how to implement this within my validation script so that I don't need to make another http request to a separate js file (not even sure if that's an option, as I kind of need it to work seamlessly with the existing script). Do I just call jQuery inside the existing script to prevent conflicts (as shown below?) Do I need to wrap the entire script in the ready event?

Currently, I'm not sure why this isn't working. The form still submits and reloads the page, so it seems to be ignoring the Ajax submit function.

The following includes the form markup from its PHP class and the form.validate.js file used for validation and ajax:

```
function copyTxtVal(bf) {
    if(bf.samecheck.checked == true) {
        bf.contact_name_first.value = bf.cpap_sup_name_first.value;
        bf.contact_name_last.value = bf.cpap_sup_name_last.value;
    } else {
        bf.contact_name_first.value = '';
        bf.contact_name_last.value = '';
    }
}

// Add the novalidate attribute when the JS loads
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.validate');

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].setAttribute('novalidate', true);
}

// Validate the field
var hasError = function (field) {

    // Don't validate submits, buttons, file and reset inputs, and disabled fields
    if(field.disabled || field.type === 'file' || field.type === 'reset' || field.type === 'submit' || field.type === 'button') return;

    // Get Validity
    var validity = field.validity;

    // Get valid, return null
    if(validity.valid) return;

    // If field is required and empty
    if (validity.valueMissing) return 'Please fill out this field.';

    // If not the right type
    if (validity.typeMismatch) {

        if(field.type === 'email') return 'Please enter an email address.';

        if(field.type === 'url') return 'Please enter a URL.';
    }

    // If too short
    if (validity.tooShort) return 'Please lengthen this text to ' + field.getAttribute('minLength') + ' characters or more. You are currently using ' + field.value.length + ' characters.';

    // If too long
    if (validity.tooLong) return 'Please short this text to no more than ' + field.getAttribute('maxLength') + ' characters. You are currently using ' + field.value.length + ' characters.';

    // If number input isn't a number
    if (validity.badInput) return 'Please enter a number.';

    // If a number value doesn't match the step interval
    if (validity.stepMismatch) return 'Please select a valid value.';

    // If a number field is over the max
    if (validity.rangeOverflow) return 'Please select a smaller value.';

    // If a number field is below the min
    if (validity.rangeUnderflow) return 'Please select a larger value.';

    // If pattern doesn't match
    if (validity.patternMismatch) {

        // If pattern info is included, return custom error
        if (field.hasAttribute('title')) return field.getAttribute('title');

        // Otherwise, generic error
        return 'Please match the requested format.';
    }

    // If all else fails, return a generic catchall error
    return 'The value you entered for this field is invalid.';

};

var showError = function(field, error){
    // Add error class to field
    field.classList.add('error');

    // Get field id or name
    var id = field.id || field.name;
    if (!id) return;

    // Check if error message field already exists
    // If not, create one
    var message = field.form.querySelector('.error-message#error-for-' + id );
    if (!message) {
        message = document.createElement('div');
        message.className = 'error-message';
        message.id = 'error-for-' + id;
        field.parentNode.insertBefore( message, field.nextSibling );
    }

    // Add ARIA role to the field
    field.setAttribute('aria-describedby', 'error-for-' + id);

    // Update error message
    message.innerHTML = error;

    // Show error message
    message.style.display = 'block';
    message.style.visibility = 'visible';

}

var removeError = function(field) {
    // Remove the error message

    // Remove error class to field
    field.classList.remove('error');

    // Remove ARIA role from the field
    field.removeAttribute('aria-describedby');

    // Get field id or name
    var id = field.id || field.name;
    if (!id) return;

    // Check if an error message is in the DOM
    var message = field.form.querySelector('.error-message#error-for-' + id + '');
    if (!message) return;

    // If so, hide it
    message.innerHTML = '';
    message.style.display = 'none';
    message.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};

//Listen to all blur events
document.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
    // Only run if field is in a form to be validated by our custom script
    if (!event.target.form.classList.contains('validate')) return;

    // Validate field
    var error = hasError(event.target);

    // If there's an error, show it
    if(error){
        showError(event.target, error);
        return;
    }

    //Otherwise, remove any existing error msg
    removeError(event.target);
}, true);

// Check all fields on submit
document.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

    // Only run on forms flagged for validation
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('validate')) return;

    // Get all of the form elements
    var fields = event.target.elements;

    // Validate each field
    // Store the first field with an error to a variable so we can bring it into focus later
    var error, hasErrors;
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        error = hasError(fields[i]);
        if (error) {
            showError(fields[i], error);
            if (!hasErrors) {
                hasErrors = fields[i];
            }
        }
    }

    // If there are errors, don't submit form and focus on first element with error
    if (hasErrors) {
        event.preventDefault();
        hasErrors.focus();
    } 
    // Call self invoking jQuery function to handle form submit by Ajax if validation passes
    else {
        (function($){
            var form = $('#cpapsupform');
            var formMessages = $('#cpap-form-messages');

            // Is this line below necessary if I've done this in the normal js above?
            $(form).submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                // Serialize Form Data
                var formData = $(form).serialize();
                //Submit the form via AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(form).attr('action'),
                    data: formData
                })

                .done(function(response) {
                    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
                    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
                    $(formMessages).addClass('success');

                    // Set the message text.
                    $(formMessages).text(response);

                    // Clear the form.
                    $('#cpap_sup_name_first').val('');
                    $('#cpap_sup_name_last').val('');
                    $('#contact_name_first').val('');
                    $('#contact_name_last').val('');
                    $('#cpap_contact_email').val('');
                    $('#cpap_contact_phone').val('');
                    $('#cpap_patient_dob').val('');
                    $('#cpap_patient_zip').val('');
                })

                .fail(function(data) {
                    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
                    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                    $(formMessages).addClass('error');

                    // Set the message text.
                    if (data.responseText !== '') {
                        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
                    } else {
                        $(formMessages).text('An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    }
}, false);
```

Here is the form markup (excerpted from the php form class I am using):

```
<?php
<div id="cpap-form-area">
    <div id="cpap-form-messages"></div>
    <div class="cpap-form-greet">
        <p>Some text goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="" id="cpapsupform" class="validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" >             
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Patient Name</legend>
            <div class="p-firstname">
                <label for="cpap_sup_name_first">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="cpap_sup_name_first" id="cpap_sup_name_first" value="<?php echo $display['cpap_sup_name_first']; ?>" required />
            </div>
            <div class="p-lastname">
                <label for="cpap_sup_name_last">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="cpap_sup_name_last" id="cpap_sup_name_last" value="<?php echo $display['cpap_sup_name_last']; ?>" required />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>          
            <legend>Point of Contact</legend>
            <div class="samename">
                <div class="cpap_input_alt">
                    <input id="samecheck" type="checkbox" name="samecheck" onchange="copyTxtVal(this.form);">
                </div>
                <label for="samecheck">Use same as above</label>
            </div>
            <div class="c-firstname">
                <label for="contact_name_first">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="contact_name_first" id="contact_name_first" value="<?php echo $display['contact_name_first']; ?>" required />
            </div>
            <div class="c-lastname">
                <label for="contact_name_last">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="contact_name_last" id="contact_name_last" value="<?php echo $display['contact_name_last']; ?>" required />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Details</legend>
            <div class="cpap-email-contact">
                <label for="cpap_contact_email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="cpap_contact_email" id="cpap_contact_email" value="<?php echo $display['cpap_contact_email']; ?>" title="The domain portion of the email after '@' is invalid." pattern="^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*(\.\w{2,})+$" required />
            </div>
            <div class="cpap-tel-contact">
                <label for="cpap_contact_phone">Phone:<br /><span class="tiny-txt">(10 digits; no spaces)</span></label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="cpap_contact_phone" id="cpap_contact_phone" value="<?php echo $display['cpap_contact_phone']; ?>" pattern="\d{10}" required />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Patient Date of Birth</legend>
            <div class="cpap-dob">
                <label for="cpap_patient_dob">Birthdate: <br /><span class="tiny-txt">(MM/DD/YYYY)</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="cpap_patient_dob" id="cpap_patient_dob" value="<?php echo $display['cpap_patient_dob']; ?>" title="Your date looks incorrect, or it doesn't match the required format." max-length="10" pattern="((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))/(([0-2]\d)|([3][01]))/((19|20)\d{2})" required ></input>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Address Info</legend>
            <div class="cpap-zip">
                <label for="cpap_patient_zip">Patient Zipcode:<br /><span class="tiny-txt">(first 5 digits only)</span></label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="cpap_patient_zip" id="cpap_patient_zip" value="<?php echo $display['cpap_patient_zip']; ?>" required ></input>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" id="cpapAjaxButton" name="cpapAjaxButton">Submit Request</button>
        <p class="form-msg">All fields must be completed</p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php wp_nonce_field('submit_cpap_form','nonce_field_for_submit_cpap_form'); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The self-invoking function in the `else` is redundant. If the code execution flows into the `else`, you don't need a self-invoking function. Just have the code that should run.

Comment: Why not just call the `.reset()` method on your form element instead of manually resetting each form field's value back to an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do have a syntax error in that you are missing the opening curly brace of your `else` branch right here:

```
// Call self invoking jQuery function to handle form submit by Ajax if validation passes
else (function($){
```

It should be:

```
// Call self invoking jQuery function to handle form submit by Ajax if validation passes
else { (function($){
```

And, to avoid these kinds of errors, good indentation and formatting of code goes a long way, so really, this would be the best way to write it:

```
// Call self invoking jQuery function to handle form submit by Ajax if validation passes
else {
  (function($) {
```

Now, to you main point. As long as you have referenced the JQuery library prior to your code needing to use it, you just go ahead and use JQuery when and where you need to. If you need some page initialization work done, then yes, a "document ready" function should be passed into the JQuery object. But, apart from that, you can leverage JQuery whenever you need to so the self-invoking function you have inside of your `else` branch is redundant - - if code execution enters that branch, you don't invoke JQuery again, you just use it.

Also, you start off with:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
```

But, the `document` object doesn't have a `submit` event. The event listener should be set up on the `form` element that is going to be submitted.

You also have some unnecessary variables and in a couple of cases, you set your variables equal to JQuery objects, but then passed those objects into the JQuery object again later as if they were regular DOM objects.

Here is your cleaned up code. Check the comments carefully for what changes were made and why. Also, this is the best we can do with answers since you didn't provide the `hasError` and `showError` functions and your HTML as well.

```js
// The document object doesn't get submitted, the form does.
// Also this sytax finds every form that has the "validate" class,
// so there is no need to test for that in the callback function
$("form.validate").on('submit', function (event) {

  // Get all of the form elements
  var fields = event.target.elements;

  // Always initialize your variables. Set them to null if you don't know the value to use yet
  // Also, the "error" and "hasError" variables are not needed. You'll see why in a couple of lines down.
  var hasErrors = null;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  
    // I'm assuming you have a working "hasError" function that returns a boolean 
    // So, just take that return value and make that the basis for the if condition -- no 
    // need to store it just to test it on the next line.
    if (hasError(fields[i])) {
    
        // I'm assuming you have a working "showError" function. If we've entered into this 
        // branch of the code, we know that "hasError" returned true, so we can just pass that
        // directly into the "showError" function instead of the "error" variable that we've
        // now gotten rid of.
        showError(fields[i], true);  
        
        // No need to test here. There is an error.
        hasErrors = fields[i];
    }
  }

  // If there are errors, don't submit form and focus on first element with error
  if (hasErrors) {
    event.preventDefault();
    hasErrors.focus();   
  } else {
  
    // You don't need a self-invoking function here. Just write the code that should execute  
    
    // It is a common convention to name variables that store references to JQuery objects
    // with a leading  $ to distinguish them as such and not regular DOM objects
    var $form = $('#cpapsupform');
    var $formMessages = $('#cpap-form-messages');

    // Submit the form via AJAX
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $form.attr('action'), // $form is already a JQuery object, don't pass it to JQuery again
       data: $form.serialize()  // <-- You had semi-colon here, which you shouldn't have
    }).done(function(response) {
      // $formMessages is already a JQuery object, don't pass it to JQuery again
      $formMessages.removeClass('error');
      $formMessages.addClass('success');

      // Set the message text.
      $formMessages.text(response);

      // Just use the DOM form.reset() method here instead of resetting each form field
      $form[0].reset();
      
    }).fail(function(data) {
      // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
      $formMessages.removeClass('success');
      $formMessages.addClass('error');

      // Set the message text.
      if (data.responseText !== '') {
        $formMessages.text(data.responseText);
      } else {
        $formMessages.text('An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
      }
      
    });
    
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="GET" class="validate">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="#" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this... It will take me a few moments to digest, but man I love a good solid explanation. Very helpful. I did vote the answer up as useful, but my rep is pretty low as this is my first time posting on SOF... but thank you.

Comment: @nrstx You're welcome. I just noticed a small typo in my answer and have updated it.

Comment: when you mention referencing jQuery, is this something that is done upstream in the JS code, or is it completed if I've enqueued the jQuery library and have loaded it into the head or footer (via WP, although I know that is maybe a little off-topic.) In other words, I'm loading jQuery into the page... is that the same as referencing?

Comment: It's done with an HTML `<script>` element. You can see it as the top line of the HTML in my code. And, yes, that's the same thing as referencing it.

Comment: Looks like it's working! I had commented a minute ago, but realized I had done something stupid. The only thing I had to do was insert `event.preventDefault();` into the else statement to prevent the submit from reloading the page. I still need to tidy up a few other things, but it looks like your input really helped out and the form submits without reloading the page. Thanks again, @Scott

Answer (score 0):

jQuery IS Javascript, so of course you can use them together. I think your problem might lie in you not properly bracketing your else statement:

```
else { (function($){ // was missing brace after 'else'
    var form = $('#cpapsupform');
    var formMessages = $('#cpap-form-messages');

        ....

    })(jQuery);
}//closing else brace
```